# Android android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelsAccess error

Tags: java, android

I see this error being reported via flurry, but have no idea what it could relate to or how to find where the error could be in my Android code.

```
class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Msg: android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelsAccess:823 (x + width must be <= bitmap.width())
```

Does anyone have an idea what kind of error this could relate to?

Answer (score 4):

your code must contain previously a call to the method:

`yourBitmap.getPixels (pixels, offset, stride, x, y, width, height);`

the exception is thrown due to the fact that:

your starting x coordinate + the amount you want to grab from the current line, exceeds your source bitmap width.

Here is a picture that may better explain the situation:

[image]

Hope this helped.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //encoding method
        Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String str) throws WriterException {
         int black = 0xFF000000;
         int white = 0xFFFFFFFF;

         int width=400;
         int height=400;

            BitMatrix result;
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            try {
                result = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(str,
                        BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,height ,width , null);

                int w = result.getWidth();
                int h = result.getHeight();
                int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
                for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                    int offset = y * w;
                    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                        pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? black : white;
                    }
                }
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
//Use the same value of the height and width respectively    
                bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, 400, 0, 0, 400, 400);
            } catch (Exception iae) {
                iae.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
```